# jQuery: Detect Object Property Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, attributes, onchange

I would like to detect if any of an object's property has changed. Something like:

```
var object = { property: 'value' };
$(object).onPropertyChange(function(property, newValue){
    console.log('object changed: ', property, newValue);
})
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some JS plugins like [Watch JS](https://gist.github.com/melanke/1627705). this keep tracks of whole object changes or even if a single attribute has changed.